# Переключение между стилями Swing

Tags: java, swing

Как переключать стили отображения (Look and Feel) в `Swing`? Т.е. `metal`, `windows`, `motif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Масса способов. Все изложено в документации и туториалах. Например [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(String полный_путь_к_классу);
```

или

`UIManager.setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeel экземпляр_класса);`

К примеру:

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

или же

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

а для установки системного LaF используйте

```
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | 
                     IllegalAccessException
                    | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```